# criar botão imprimir para cada uma da tabela

Tags: php, html

Tenho 3 tabelas diferentes na mesma página php e pretendo imprimir cada tabela em separado uma das outras.

Código que estou a utilizar:

```
<?php
echo $tabela3;
echo $tabela4;
echo $tabela5;
echo "<td><form action='#' method='post'><input type=button name=imprime value='Imprimir' onclick='javascript:DoPrinting();'><td></form></center>";
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
function DoPrinting()
{
   if (!window.print)
   {
      alert("Use o Netscape ou Internet Explorer \n nas versões 4.0 ou superior!")
      return
   }
   window.print()
}
</script>
```

Mas desta forma sempre que faço imprimir, imprime as três tabelas, mas eu queria por exemplo só imprimir a primeira tabela e as outras duas não ou imprimir a última e as outras duas não imprimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Começo por referir que consegue controlar o que imprime numa página apenas com  CSS, escondendo os elementos que não quer que apareçam.

Isso é feito quer com o `@media print` na página em questão, em acrescento ao resto do CSS que ela já tenha:

```
@media print {
    .elementos-a-esconder-na-impressao {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Ou criando dois arquivos diferentes de estilo, um para visualização normal e outro para impressão, que inclui no topo com `<link>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css" media="screen"><!--normal-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="impressao.css" media="print"><!--para impressão-->
```

---

No seu caso no entanto é mais complicado pois quer imprimir 3 versões diferentes na mesma página com base num click de um botão, e cada uma mostrando coisas diferentes. Nesse caso tem mesmo de se servir de Javascript para fazer isso.

Servindo-me de uma [resposta já existente no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255438/6087092) pode fazer assim:

```
function printElem(elemID)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elemID).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

Agora para a conseguir utilizar essa função precisa de definir etiquetas e id's respetivos para cada uma delas. Nesse sentido pode alterar os `echos` que das tabelas para:

```
echo "<div id='tabela3'>$tabela3</div>";
echo "<div id='tabela4'>$tabela4</div>";
echo "<div id='tabela5'>$tabela5</div>";
```

E agora pode ter 3 botões cada um imprimindo a tabela correspondente, através do seu `id`:

```
echo "<button onclick='printElem(\"tabela3\")'>Imprimir tabela 3</button>";
echo "<button onclick='printElem(\"tabela4\")'>Imprimir tabela 4</button>";
echo "<button onclick='printElem(\"tabela5\")'>Imprimir tabela 5</button>";
```